# Reading from CSV file but mostly None values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file with data in most fields. I can read this csv file in Pandas with no problem. However, when I try and read it in with Apache Spark, I get mostly Null values as shown in the screenshot. I have no idea why. This file is actually 400,000+ rows, which is why I am using Apache Spark, but I have the same problem when I take only 20 rows.

```
    df = spark.read.csv('drive/My Drive/inc-20.csv', header=True)
    df.show()
```

[Apache Spark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhuci.png)

[Here is the original CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEkI.png)

Any input would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. The last column wasn't being parsed properly. Oddly, this seemed to have an impact on other columns. I dropped the last column, and this worked. Hope that helps anyone running into a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try to read the file with Schema as below

```
  df=spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true) // <-- HERE
  .csv("/home/filepath/Book1.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about what I have tried.
1. I have tried the inferSchema option and set it to True
2. I have also defined a schema ... StructType(List(StructField(ASSIGNMENT,StringType,true),StructField(RESOLUTION_CODE,StringType,true) ...
Unfortunately none of these work.